# Adding missing time stamp rows to a df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have very unusual time series data which is both irregular and has several missing values.
The data points are measured 3 times a day only on weekdays, at 10:00AM, 2:00PM, and 6:00PM, most days are missing one or two measurements, and some days are missing altogether.

My **df** looks something like this:

```
      date time            | value 
0     2020-07-30 10:00:00      5 
1     2020-07-30 14:00:00      3 
2     2020-07-31 10:00:00      6 
3     2020-07-31 14:00:00     4.5 
4     2020-07-31 18:00:00      7 
5     2020-08-03 14:00:00     5.5 
6     2020-08-04 14:00:00      5
```

I'm trying to figure out how to fill it out with the time stamps for the missing measurements, add a row with the missing time stamp and an NA value, but without adding extra times of day or any Saturdays or Sundays, so that my **df** looks like this at the end:

```
      date time            | value 
0     2020-07-30 10:00:00      5 
1     2020-07-30 14:00:00      3 
2     2020-07-30 18:00:00      NA  
3     2020-07-31 10:00:00      6 
4     2020-07-31 14:00:00     4.5  
5     2020-07-31 18:00:00      7 
6     2020-08-03 10:00:00      NA 
7     2020-08-03 14:00:00     5.5 
8     2020-08-03 18:00:00      NA
9     2020-08-04 10:00:00      NA  
10    2020-08-04 14:00:00      5 
11    2020-08-04 18:00:00      NA
```

The only thing I could come up with was pretty convoluted: write a loop to generate a row for all the dates in the desired date range * 3 (1 for each time of measurement) formatted as date times, along with a an additional week of day counter. Convert it into a df, and then drop all columns where Week of Day = 6,7, then do a join of this new df with my original df on the date time column (Outer or left - whichever one keeps all columns).

Is there any more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
{"date time": datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-07-30 10:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "value": 5},
{"date time": datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-07-30 14:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "value": 3},
{"date time": datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-07-31 10:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "value": 6},
{"date time": datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-07-31 14:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "value": 4.5},
{"date time": datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-07-31 18:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "value": 7},
{"date time": datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-08-02 14:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "value": 5.5},
{"date time": datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-08-03 14:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "value": 5},
    ]
)
```

```
# define your range of dates you're working with
range_dates = pd.date_range('2020-07-30', '2020-08-04', freq='D')
# remove weekend days
range_dates = range_dates[~range_dates.weekday.isin([5,6])]
range_dates = pd.Series(range_dates)

# here we will create a range of your 3 hours of measurements
range_times = pd.date_range('10:00:00', '18:00:00', freq='4H')
range_times = pd.Series(range_times.time)

# we combine our two ranges
index = range_dates.apply(
    lambda date: range_times.apply(
        lambda time: datetime.datetime.combine(date, time)
        )
    ).unstack()

# we reindex the dataframe and sort it
df = df.reindex(index=index).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                     value
2020-07-30 10:00:00    5.0
2020-07-30 14:00:00    3.0
2020-07-30 18:00:00    NaN
2020-07-31 10:00:00    6.0
2020-07-31 14:00:00    4.5
2020-07-31 18:00:00    7.0
2020-08-01 10:00:00    NaN
2020-08-01 14:00:00    NaN
2020-08-01 18:00:00    NaN
2020-08-02 10:00:00    NaN
2020-08-02 14:00:00    5.5
2020-08-02 18:00:00    NaN
2020-08-03 10:00:00    NaN
2020-08-03 14:00:00    5.0
2020-08-03 18:00:00    NaN
2020-08-04 10:00:00    NaN
2020-08-04 14:00:00    NaN
2020-08-04 18:00:00    NaN
```

Comment: good answer, seems you are missing the weekend filtering though

Comment: Oh, you're right! I borrow a part of your answer to fix that, thx

Answer (score 1):

you could create a filtered date range and index by it:

```
all_ts = pd.date_range(start=df['datetime'].min(), end=df['datetime'].max(), freq='H')
weekday_ts = all_ts[~all_ts.weekday.isin([5,6])]
filtered_ts = weekday_ts[weekday_ts.hour.isin([10, 14, 18])]
df.set_index(df['datetime']).reindex(filtered_ts).drop('datetime', axis=1).reset_index()
```